# Constrained language mode in remote session only on one workstation

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I was checking my organisation workstations for Meltdown/Spectre vulnerabilities with MS powershell script using invoke-command. All went well, but one workstation throwed an error.

What i was able to find out that when entering powershell remote session, the session to this particular workstation is in "ConstrainedLanguage" mode.

`[workstation]: PS [..]> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
ConstrainedLanguage`

While other working workstations have "FullLanguage" mode when entering remote powershell session.

We have active directory and group policies are applied the same to all workstations, i compared applied gpo settings to this machine, it's the same as others.

I cannot change to Full mode when i'm already in Constrained mode.
`$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = "Fulllanguage"
Cannot set property. Property setting is supported only on core types in  this language mode.`

We have a policy to allow *.psm1 file creation in TEMP folder to allow powershell to work in Fulllanguage mode.

Can anyone advice why only that one particular workstation has Constrained mode and others not. I cannot find any clues, i also cannot change it. I googled for two days, cannot find any relevant information. Thank you.

EDIT:
I even tried removing the default session configuration "microsoft.powershell" on that remote workstation and re-creating it with Enable-PSRemoting as instructed in about_remote_troubleshooting. But the result is the same, session has Constrained language mode. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

How are you remoting to that server ?
Are you connecting to a custom PowerShell end point ?
If so, the remote custom end point in that server might have created by setting `-LanguageMode` as Constrained

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't use any custom end points. I connect to every workstation in the same default way `Enter-PSSession -Computername pc-name`. I'm investigating what you said, but i can't find any command that takes "-LanguageMode" ar parameter.

Comment: Well i tried to use custom session configuration when connecting to this workstation (configuration file and startup script), but on the last step, when connecting to workstation i get errors and cannot connect. This method was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the Env variable __PSLockdownPolicy value to 0 to return to FullLanguage Mode obviously that needs restart of existing session if any.

Comment: I think i tried that. The Env variable __PSLockdownPolicy does not exist when i try to access it. I tried adding this value to registry also, to no avail. I'm on vacation now, i'll look into it more after two weeks. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks, it did not help. This variable doesn't exist by itself, it's empty or null. If i set a 0 value to it, nothing changes, situation is the same.